# Can I use @GET annotations in two methods in same class?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getRscSubTypes(){
    return AddResourceMysql.getRscSubType();
}    

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getDbTypes() {
    return AddResourceMysql.getDbType();
}
```

This is returning the following exception:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: 
Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.   But this was happened when i didn't use Consumes. When i use Consumes it always executing the 2nd method

Comment: please post full stack trace in your question so anyone can help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How request matching works

Definitely, you can have more than one method annotated with [`@GET`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/GET.html) in the same class. However, your current definition is **ambiguous**.

For more clarification, have a look at the [JAX-RS 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf):

> **3.7.2 Request Matching**
>
> A request is matched to the corresponding resource **method** or sub-resource method by comparing the normalized **request URI**, the **media type of any request entity**, and the **requested response entity format** to the metadata annotations on the resource classes and their methods. [...]

### How to fix it

You need change your method annotations to ensure you have no ambiguity. To do it, you can play with the following annotations:

- HTTP method: [`@GET`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/GET.html), [`@POST`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/POST.html), [`@PUT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/PUT.html), [`@DELETE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DELETE.html), [`@HEAD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HEAD.html) and [`@OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/OPTIONS.html)
- Request URI: [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html)
- Media type of any request entity: [`@Consumes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html)
- Requested response entity format: [`@Produces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html)

To fix it, for example, you can just add a [`@Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation with different values to each method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define multiple resource methods, which handle GET requests for the same [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type), within the same class, you have to specify a different subpath for the methods:

```
@Path("rcsubtypes")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getRscSubTypes()
{
    return AddResourceMysql.getRscSubType();
}  

@Path("dbtypes") 
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getDbTypes()
{
    return AddResourceMysql.getDbType();
}
```

The path, specified in the [`@Path`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation of this method, is a subpath of the path specified in the [`@Path`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation of the class, which is a subpath of the path you defined for your application.

To explain your behaviour, that always the second method is called, if there is no [`@Consumes`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotation present on the first method: [`@Consumes`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) defines which media type (set in the [Content-Type header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) of the request) can be accepted by the method. Without a [`@Consumes`](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) annotation all requests are accepted, but i think, if a method specifies an accepted media-type, it will be preferred.

The matching section in the jersey documentation: [3.1. Root Resource Classes](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1962)